# Subsets of a given Set of Integers whose sum is a Constant N : Java

Tags: java, math, data-structures, integer, subset-sum

Given a set of integers, how to find a subset that sums to a given value...the subset problem ?

Example : S = {1,2,4,3,2,5} and n= 7
Finding the possible subsets whose sum is n.
I tried to google out found many links,but were not clear.
How can we solve this in java and what is the data structure to be used and its complexity ?

Comment: You appear to have a List of Integer as you have duplicates. i.e. 2 twice.

Comment: It **is** the NP-complete [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) (we should ask google to index wikipedia again...)

Comment: @Andreas_D: Google failed on this search???

Comment: @Gunner (that was a joke ;-) )

Comment: Wiki entry isnt simple .. little bit abstract .

Comment: If S is always going to be 1 to N and you are looking for 1 <= m <= N. You can implement an Integer Partitioning algorithm then filter out repeated elements.

Comment: @lewellen Integre partioning algorithm ,howz that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wont give you any code,  but explain how it works.

1. Run a loop from `0 to (2^k-1)`
2. For each value in 1, a 1 in its binary representation indicates that this value is chosen and 0 otherwise.
3. Test to see if the sum of chosen numbers is equal to **n**.

The above method will evaluate each possible subset of the given set.

If the upper limit of the values is small, then Dynamic Programming Approach could be used.

Comment: @Gunner .. Man u fired exactly thre .. crystal clear .. thts what google culdnt help ..

Comment: @Gunner Now the complexity I think is O(2^n) ... Do we have any other ways to solve it ?

Comment: Yes, the complexity of this one is 2^n. There is a O(k*n) approach also, where n is the sum and k number of elements. It has the added pitfall of using O(n) extra memory. The idea is to keep track of what has been made thus far using elements upto, say j, then to each if you add a[j+1], you can also know the sum you can make using elements upto a[j+1] and so on.

Comment: @Gunner yup .. thnx for that ... i thnk u said dynamic programming .. how wil that help here .. I can find it in wiki subset problem .. entry but little abstract .. canu just put some light on that . is it kind of recursion .. ?

Comment: @Gunner The complexity (difficulty of solution) of subset sum can be viewed as depending on two parameters, N, the number of decision variables, and P, the precision of the problem (stated as the number of binary place values that it takes to state the problem). (Note: here the letters N and P mean something different than what they mean in the NP class of problems.)                          <br>    entry in wiki ...   <br>                N is the number of elemnts but I culdnt get what p is ? Is p the number of places of sum when represented in bits ?

Comment: @Gunner Horowitz and Sahni's algorithm -- i sthis the second approach that u werer talkng abt ?

Answer (score 2):

In three steps:

1. Find the powerset of S (the set of all subsets of S)
2. Compute the sum of each subset
3. Filter out subsets that did not sum to 7.

Comment: Programmatically how to find the power set .. thats the  question btw ?